# Using jQuery to fade background images

Tags: jquery

I know this questions has been asked many times before -- but I haven't been able to find an answer that will help me.

I'm hoping there is a solution for my specific issue.  I'd like to be able to fade in and fade out a series of background images on a site I am working on right now.  I don't think I can use conventional fader scripts because the images I am fading are wider than normal and I don't want horizontal scroll bars to appear.  (1476x253)

I've set up a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/michaelharmon/szvMH/ if anyone wants to help me tackle this issue.

Here is a link to another sample image to use in the fade testing:

http://209.142.68.153/images/cityscape-home.jpg

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: that's quite a div tower you have there. which images would you like faded where? ps: selectors like "#content .page-home .main .content-main .right .latest" are TERRIFYING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), with the fade effect to accomplish what you need. The [options reference page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) shows that you can set container height and width, as well as CSS parameters before and after the transition - that should be enough to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I have used the Cycle plugin before and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this jQuery plugin - http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/

Its very simple to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.backstretch("URL TO YOUR IMAGE", {speed: 800});
</script>
```